# Action is called twice (mouse up/down) when Target is clicked in Cocoa/objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, target, nsdatepicker

I have a NSDatePicker (target), and datePickerAction (action)

```
- (IBAction)datePickerAction:(id)sender
{

    if( [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent] modifierFlags] & 
       NSShiftKeyMask )
        NSLog(@"shift pressed %@", [datePicker dateValue]);

    else
        NSLog(@"hello %@", [datePicker dateValue]);

}
```

It works well as when I click a date in NSDatePicker object, the method(action) is called, the problem is that the method is called twice - mouse down/up.

Can I make the method called only once (up or down)?

### EDIT

I only have the method to be selected.

[image]

And this is connection inspector.
[image]

Comment: For which event did you add the target-action pair?

Comment: @MHC : I just control drag/drop from NSDatePicker object in xib to the datePickerAction method. I didn't have any event related setup.

Comment: You have to connect some action to the method. Look at the connections panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you cannot set `NSDatePicker` (or `NSDatePickerCell`, to be specific) up this way in Interface Builder, but instead have to do it programmatically.

Here's a workaround that performs fine for me:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Assuming @property (assign) IBOutlet NSDatePickerCell *pickerCell;
    [self.pickerCell sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDown]; // or NSLeftMouseUp or what have you...
}
```

Note that you **cannot** use `NSLeftMouseDownMask` here! (Well, of cause you can...but it won't help.)

Answer (score -1):

You typically want to add a target and action for a particular event. When you are making a connection using IB, look at the Connections Inspector. There is a list of control events to which you can set a target-action pair. Choose an event and drag to an action method.

Comment: I checked the connection inspector, and I couldn't find the event. Could you elaborate the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @prosseek that advice doesn't apply on the Mac as of OS 10.6 as it is specific to UIKit. I don't know about Lion, though.